# React Native Text Wrap

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

Currently I am developing a react native application. I have the problem that the text is wrapping, but the text wraps so that sometimes the last word in a line overflows the container, even if there is space left in the last line. How do I fix this?

```
import { Text, View, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const TextCard = () => {
  const emojy = "Sonne";
  const header = "Solarenergie unterstützen";
  const content =
    "Damit unterstützt du eines der vielen Solarprojekte von Atmosfair auf der ganzen Welt";
  const footer = "Schon ab 6€ 260kg CO2 pro Jahr binden";

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{emojy}</Text>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{header}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.contentText}>{content}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.footerText}>{footer}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#CCC",
    width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.85,
    height: 130,
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  contentText: {
    fontWeight: "500",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#444",
  },
  footerText: {
    fontWeight: "300",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#777",
  },
  headerText: {
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#444",
  },
  textContainer: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  },
});

export default TextCard;
```

Comment: Can you share `EmmisionActivity` component. Just to see the style you've implemented for the component.

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Sorry I shared the wrong code, now all needed styles are in the code

Answer (score 0):

Change your **`textContainer`** style like this.

```css
  textContainer: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  }
```